# Was there any overlap between United Space Alliance and United Launch Alliance?

Tags: space-shuttle, united-states, manufacturing, ula

[United Space Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Space_Alliance) was a joint venture including Boeing and Lockheed-Martin, which provided services and operations for the Space Shuttle program.

[United Launch Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Launch_Alliance) is a joint venture including Boeing and Lockheed-Martin, which manufactures launch vehicles.

Other than their similar names and their common Boeing-LM parentage, **did these companies intentionally share anything in common?**  People?  Facilities?  Divisions?  Intellectual property?

Answer (score 1):

As you note United Space Alliance was for manned space programs only (shuttle), United Launch Alliance was expendable only. No overlap unless you consider employees quitting a job from one company to go work for the other company "sharing". But that happens between contractors and NASA employees all the time at KSC / the cape.

Comment: USA had quite a bit of ISS work too, at JSC. Not enough to stay alive after shuttle though.